# JavaScript runtime error in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I get this error with some JavaScript on my page:

`JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'ToggleValidators' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

I have been trying to fix this for ages and I can't seem to get it right.

What the script is supposed to do is turn off the required field validators on a page and then toggle them on when a button is pressed.

The JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').fadeIn(500);

    //Turn off all validation = it's switched on dynamically
    $.each(Page_Validators, function (index, validator) {
        ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
    });
});

function ToggleValidators('g2') 
{
  $.each(Page_Validators, function (index, validator) {
        if (validator.validationGroup == g2) 
        {
            ValidatorEnable(validator, true);
        }
        else 
        {
            ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
        }
    });
}
```

And on the button:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="g2" OnClientClick="ToggleValidators('g2');" />`

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Your function argument has quotes around it...

Comment: It looks like your code is inside a `script` tag with `src` attribute. You have to put your code in its own `script` element. Otherwise the code won't even be evaluated. But since your HTML is a bit incomplete, this is just a guess. Provide a more complete example of your code and will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @FelixKling That was the problem! Thankyou. Its always the smallest things you miss

Comment: Made it an answer. If an answer helped, you should accept it (by clicking the checkmark next to) to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message basically means that the function `ToggleValidators` cannot be found, i.e. it can be that it was never created.

It looks like your code is inside a `script` tag with `src` attribute. You have to put your code in its own script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    // your code here
</script>
```

Otherwise the code won't even be evaluated (and the function won't be created, just like the error message said).

Of course there might be other problems with your code (such as the quotes around the parameter definition).

Comment: This was the main issue though and this fixed it :/